# Superscript in legends in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to get this text output in the legend:

[image]

I tried the following:

```
lab1 <- c(expression((CD44 (lo)^2 T Cells)]),
          expression((CD44 (hi)^2 CD69 (lo)^2 T Cells)]), 
         expression((CD44 (hi)^2 CD69 (hi)^2 CD103 (lo)^2 T Cells)
expression(CD44 (hi)^2 CD69 (hi)^2 CD103 (hi)^2 T Cells))
```

```
lab2 <- c(expression(paste(CD44 (lo)^2 T Cells)]),
          expression(paste(CD44 (hi)^2 CD69 (lo)^2 T Cells)]), 
         expression(paste(CD44 (hi)^2 CD69 (hi)^2 CD103 (lo)^2 T Cells)
           expression(paste(CD44 (hi)^2 CD69 (hi)^2 CD103 (hi)^2 T Cells))
```

```
lab3 <- c(bquote((CD44 (lo)^2 T Cells)),
               bquote((CD44 (hi)^2 CD69 (lo)^2 T Cells)),
                 bquote((CD44 (hi)^2 CD69 (hi)^2 CD103 (lo)^2 T Cells)),
                bquote((CD44 (hi)^2 CD69 (hi)^2 CD103 (hi)^2 T Cells)))
```

My code:

```
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyverse, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(stringr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(matrixStats, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(pheatmap, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(heatmaps, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(ggplot2, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

dfc <- read.csv(url("https://github.com/learnseq/learning/raw/main/GSE133399_Fig2_FPKM.csv"))

values <- c('S100a10', 'Esm1', 'Itgb1', 'Anxa2', 'Hist1h1b', 
                                                'Il2rb', 'Lgals1', 'Mki67', 'Rora', 'S100a4', 
                                                'S100a6', 'Adam8', 'Areg', 'Bcl2l1', 'Calca', 
                                                'Capg', 'Ccr2', 'Cd44', 'Csda', 'Ehd1', 
                                                'Id2', 'Il10', 'Il1rl1', 'Il2ra', 'Lmna', 
                                                'Maf', 'Penk', 'Podnl1', 'Tiam1', 'Vim',
                                                'Ern1', 'Furin', 'Ifng', 'Igfbp7', 'Il13', 
                                                'Il4', 'Il5', 'Nrp1', 'Ptprs', 'Rbpj', 
                                                'Spry1', 'Tnfsf11', 'Vdr', 'Xcl1', 'Bmpr2', 
                                                'Csf1', 'Dst', 'Foxp3', 'Itgav', 'Itgb8', 
                                                'Lamc1', 'Myo1e', 'Pmaip1', 'Prdm1', 'Ptpn5', 
                                                'Ramp1', 'Sdc4')

dfg <- dfc[match(rev(values), dfc$tracking_id), ]

dfg$CD44low_rep <- rowMeans(dfg[,c('CD44low_rep1', 'CD44low_rep2')], na.rm=TRUE)
dfg$CD44hi_CD69low_rep <- rowMeans(dfg[,c('CD44hi_CD69low_rep1', 'CD44hi_CD69low_rep2')], na.rm=TRUE)
dfg$CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103low_rep <- rowMeans(dfg[,c('CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103low_rep1', 'CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103low_rep2')], na.rm=TRUE)
dfg$CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103hi_rep <- rowMeans(dfg[,c('CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103hi_rep1', 'CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103hi_rep2')], na.rm=TRUE)
rownameshm <-paste(dfg[,1])
colnameshm <- paste(dQuote(colnames(dfg[0, 10:13])), collapse = ", ")
dfg$Mean <- rowMeans(dfg[,10:13])
dfg$sd <- rowSds(as.matrix(dfg[,10:13]))

zScore <- function(p){
for(n in 10:13){
    p[[n]]=(as.numeric(p[[n]])-as.numeric(p[[14]]))/as.numeric(p[[15]])
    }
return(p)
}

Matrix_zScore <- t(apply(dfg,1,zScore))

Matrix_zScore_temp <- mapply(Matrix_zScore[,10:13], FUN=as.numeric)
Matrix_zScore_temp <- matrix(data=Matrix_zScore_temp, ncol=4, nrow=57)
Matrix_zScore_temp1<-as.data.frame(Matrix_zScore_temp)

rownames(Matrix_zScore_temp) <- dfg$tracking_id
plot_frame <- reshape2::melt(Matrix_zScore_temp)

library(repr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
options(repr.plot.width=5, repr.plot.height=8)

#lab1 <- c(expression((CD44 (lo)^2 T Cells)]),
#          expression((CD44 (hi)^2 CD69 (lo)^2 T Cells)]), 
#         expression((CD44 (hi)^2 CD69 (hi)^2 CD103 (lo)^2 T Cells)
#  expression(CD44 (hi)^2 CD69 (hi)^2 CD103 (hi)^2 T Cells))

lab2 <- c(expression(paste(CD44 (lo)^2 T Cells)]),
          expression(paste(CD44 (hi)^2 CD69 (lo)^2 T Cells)]), 
         expression(paste(CD44 (hi)^2 CD69 (hi)^2 CD103 (lo)^2 T Cells)
           expression(paste(CD44 (hi)^2 CD69 (hi)^2 CD103 (hi)^2 T Cells))


#lab3 <- c(bquote((CD44 (lo)^2 T Cells)),
#               bquote((CD44 (hi)^2 CD69 (lo)^2 T Cells)),
#                 bquote((CD44 (hi)^2 CD69 (hi)^2 CD103 (lo)^2 T Cells)),
#                bquote((CD44 (hi)^2 CD69 (hi)^2 CD103 (hi)^2 T Cells)))

ggplot(plot_frame, aes(Var2, Var1, fill = value)) + 
  geom_tile(color = "white", position = position_dodge(), show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_point(data = data.frame(Var2 = 1:4, Var1 = "", value = 0), size = 5,
             aes(color = factor(Var2))) +
  geom_point(data = data.frame(Var2 = 1:4, Var1 = " ", value = 1), alpha = 0) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "forestgreen", "red4", "blue4"),
                     labels = (lab2,
                     guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = NA))) +
  scale_y_discrete(position = "right") +
  labs(y = "", fill = "", color = " ", x = "")  +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("#3C57A8", "white", "#DE2D29"),
                       breaks = c(1.5, 0, -1.5),
                       labels = c("1.0", "0", "-1.0"),
                       limits = c(-1.5, 1.5),
                       space = "Lab",
                       na.value = "grey50",
                       guide = "colourbar",
                       aesthetics = "fill") +
  theme_minimal() + 
theme (panel.grid.major = element_blank(), axis.text.y.right = element_text(margin = margin(l = unit(-5, "cm")))) +
theme (axis.text.y = element_text(face="italic", size=7, color="black")) +
    guides(
        fill = guide_colourbar(
            title = "Relative gene expression \n (z score)",
            title.position = "right",
            title.theme = element_text(angle = -90, size = 7.5),
            direction = "vertical",
            ticks = TRUE
        )) +
theme(
    legend.justification = c(-0.9, 0),
    legend.direction = "vertical",
    legend.key.size = unit(0.6, "cm"),
    legend.key.width = unit(0.2,"cm"),
    legend.title.align = 0.5,
    axis.text.x = element_blank())
```

I tried these based on some question in this community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example seemed unnecessarily complex for just creating a legend. Here's a simplified example

```
library(ggplot2)
labs <- expression(
  CD44^{lo}~"T Cells",
  CD44^{hi}~CD69^{lo}~"T Cells", 
  CD44^{hi}~CD69^{hi}~CD103^{lo}~"T Cells",
  CD44^{hi}~CD69^{hi}~CD103^{hi}~"T Cells")

dd <- data.frame(x=1:4, y=1:4, z=letters[1:4])
ggplot(dd) +
  aes(x,y, color=z) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("black", "forestgreen", "red4", "blue4"),
    labels=labs)
```

Note that `expression()` actually returns a container object so you can just pass in all your expressions in a single call to `expression()`. Also, review the syntax allowed on the `?plotmath` help page.

This will return a legend that looks like

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @MrFlick , how can make the text be next to the dots? you can observe that the first two are far to the right away from the dots.

Comment: You can add `+ theme(legend.text.align = 0)`

Comment: It seems that it has no effect on position in my code, but I tried with your simple example and it worked, when I try within my code, it has no effect. @MrFlick

Comment: It's likely one of your many other `theme()` calls are interfering. Start from something simple and add one line at a time to see how it changes.

Comment: I just noticed, when I use `+ theme(legend.text.align = 0) ` the other legend moves, but not the legend that I want to be aligned! Any input? @MrFlick